# eslint showing unexpected use of comma, no-sequences for an array

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have the following code, and eslint keeps showing `no-sequences` warning.

```
const full = {};

["firstname", "lastname", "spouse"].forEach(key => {
})

["cellphone", "phone"].forEach(key => {
})
```

Though the error is on the second `forEach` block, the warning only appears when I put the first `forEach` block. is this an eslint bug?

[here](https://eslint.org/demo#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiY29uc3QgZnVsbCA9IHt9O1xuXG5bXCJmaXJzdG5hbWVcIiwgXCJsYXN0bmFtZVwiLCBcInNwb3VzZVwiXS5mb3JFYWNoKGtleSA9PiB7XG59KVxuXG5bXCJjZWxscGhvbmVcIiwgXCJwaG9uZVwiXS5mb3JFYWNoKGtleSA9PiB7XG59KSIsIm9wdGlvbnMiOnsicGFyc2VyT3B0aW9ucyI6eyJlY21hVmVyc2lvbiI6MTIsInNvdXJjZVR5cGUiOiJtb2R1bGUiLCJlY21hRmVhdHVyZXMiOnt9fSwicnVsZXMiOnsibm8tbG9vcC1mdW5jIjoyLCJuby1zZXF1ZW5jZXMiOjJ9LCJlbnYiOnsiYnJvd3NlciI6dHJ1ZX19fQ==) is the link on eslint demo editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code has no semicolon, you're basically trying to access an array in the first `forEach`:

```
["firstname", "lastname", "spouse"].forEach(key => {
})["cellphone", "phone"].forEach(key => {
})
```

Of course this is not correct. To fix this problem, just add a semicolon:

```
["firstname", "lastname", "spouse"].forEach(key => {
}); // Add a semicolon here

["cellphone", "phone"].forEach(key => {
}); // Here it is not necessary, but it is a good practice to avoid that kind of error
```

This will fix the error because semicolons point out the end of a [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements), so ESLint will be able to understand that there are two different statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semi-colon at the end of the first `forEach` call, so your code is equivalent to:

```js
["firstname", "lastname", "spouse"].forEach(key => {
})["cellphone", "phone"].forEach(key => {})
```

That is attempting to get the value of the `"phone"` property of the return value of `forEach` (which is `undefined`). `[]` is interpreted to be bracket notation instead of an array literal due to automatic semicolon insertion. ESLint is pointing out the use of the comma operator in `"cellphone", "phone"`, which results in attempting to read the `"phone"` property.

Answer (score 0):

**I didn't know object value access is actually multiline.**

```js
const data = {"key":123}

console.log(

  data

  ["key"]

)
```

Though on newline, Would actually work and print access `data["key"]` to print `123`.